# AutoMapper Sorting List

Tags: automapper

I have this mapping defined

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Telephone, TelephoneDTO>()
.ForMember(dto => dto.Extension, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Extension))
.ForMember(dto => dto.Number, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Number))
.ForMember(dto => dto.Type, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TelephoneType.Id));
```

when i do

```
IList<TelephoneDTO> dtos = Mapper.Map<IList<Telephone>, IList<TelephoneDTO>>(tels);
```

i would like the list of TelephoneDTO to be sorted by the Type.

How can i do that ?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AutoMapper is used for mapping, not for sorting. You could sort the list once the mapping being done:

```
IList<TelephoneDTO> dtos = Mapper
    .Map<IList<Telephone>, IList<TelephoneDTO>>(tels)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Type)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: It's a pity there's no option for sorting during mapping though, especially when dealing with a deep object graph.

Comment: Especially given that when going from a Collection to a List, it'd be pretty reasonable to consider the sort order part of the map.

Answer (score -1):

or

```
IList<TelephoneDTO> dtos = Mapper
    .Map<IList<Telephone>, IList<TelephoneDTO>>(tels.OrderBy(x => x.Type))
```